# How to move ** return (this.innerText.length <= 200) ** to a function?

Tags: javascript

i have this

```
  onkeypress="return (this.innerText.length <= 200);"
```

in a contenteditable div.

works fine.

but when i try to move it to a function

```
<script>
    function aa(){
    document.getElementById('div_id').innerText.length <= 200;
    }
</script>
```

change the contentdiv's execution style

```
  onkeypress="aa();"
```

it no longer works.

i added `alert('test');` just to ensure the `aa()` was being executed. it was being executed just fine.

Comment: You are missing `return` keyword;

Comment: Probably you want to use a function to avoid repeating that code. Just add event listeners with JS instead of using content attribute event handlers in the HTML.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Handle inside HTML

You left out the `return`

```js
function aa(){
  // MUST ALSO RETURN HERE
  return (document.getElementById('div_id').innerText.length <= 200);
}
```

```html
<!-- NEED EXTRA RETURN HERE -->
<div id="div_id" onkeypress="return aa()" contenteditable>
    <!--THIS ARE 200 CHARACTERS--> ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRS
</div>
```

### No handling inside HTML

```js
var div = document.getElementById('div_id2')
div.onkeypress = function(){
  return (div.innerText.length <= 200);
}
```

```html
<div id="div_id2" contenteditable>
    <!--THIS ARE 200 CHARACTERS--> ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRS
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You are missing `return` keyword;

```js
function check(editor) {
  return editor.innerHTML.length <= 200;
}
```

```css
#editor {
  border: 1px solid grey;
  height: 100px;
}
```

```html
<div contenteditable='' id="editor" onkeypress="return check(this);">
  Try typing here ...
</div>
```